# How do I pause/play animation in Unity without the animation getting cut off

Tags: unity

I'm trying to achieve a common game behavior that when you hit an enemy, then whatever the enemy's action (animation) is, when the hit happens, the enemy pauses a bit, then continues with the animation. So everytime you hit the enemy, the enemy pauses for a bit.

I currently have this code:

```
IEnumerator StopStartMotion()
{        
    _animator.speed = 0;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.2f);
    _animator.speed = 1;
}
```

Problem is, sometimes, when I hit too early in the enemy's animation (like at the beginning of a punch), the enemy pauses, and then doesn't continue the animation where he paused for a bit. Is there a better way of doing this?

I tried animator.enabled as well, but the animation also jumps.

Comment: you have exit time for animations in unity animator. just use that

Comment: Have you tried _animator.Rebind() if not try this might solve the problem. if it do  then let me know.

Comment: use it after setting animator speed to 1.

Comment: Tthanks, will try both your suggestions. Will let you guys know if something works for me.

Comment: Rebind didn't work; not sure how to use exit time to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for my game.

I disable the *Animator* so that the enemy stays in that frame. After I'm done, I re-enable the *Animator* and the enemy animation continues.

```
IEnumerator StopStartMotion()
{        
    _animator.enabled = false;
    //DO SOMETHING HERE
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.2f);
    _animator.enabled = true;
}
```